# Use Smartcard for PXE windows install

Tags: windows, pxe, smartcard

In our environment we mostly use smartcards for administration tasks in a Windows Domain (tasks such as sensitive NAS shares access, or RDP logons).

Recently, we started using PXE boot to speed up installation process. However, we need to enter an Administrator password to start the PXE install process.

Is there a way to use a smartcard for this operation? Because using a non-secure keyboard on a non-secure machine to enter an Administrator password kind of defeats all the smartcard migration process.

Answer (score 0):

Negative answer : Before the boot there is no software on the computer
that is capable of accessing the smartcard.

A better direction would be to set up a PXE server that does not demand a password.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't mean before the boot, but after the boot image (Windows PE) is booted, there's a prompt to enter credentials to log to the Windows Server machine that has the WDS role.

Comment: That's an entirely different question from : "password to start the PXE install process". You mean you wish the Windows PE image to include your smartcard software. Customizing Windows PE is possible, but I suggest starting a new post with a clearer phrasing and specifying the make of your smartcard. As your question stands, I don't see another answer.